# Error in yii2 data display from a model

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is the controller action list which should display users in a user table if a user role is not super

```
 public function actionList()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query'=>User::find()->where(['not', 'is_super']),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('list', ['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
}
```

What could be the problem

Comment: What is `not`? Is it column name?

Comment: And, if no. Then, provide column name.

Comment: No it means find where a user is not a super user

Comment: So, what is that column name where all values are being saved. Like: is_super, is_no_super. There will be column name Right, where all values are being stored?

Comment: The column name is is_super

Comment: and value is also `is_super` for super user?

Comment: What i have set in the column (is_super) is a boolean value of 0 if false and 1 i true

Comment: Change your query to `'query' => User::find()->where(['<>','is_super',1]),`

Comment: means 0 = `not super user` and 1 = `super user` ?

Comment: Still returns an error of ...[Only variables should be passed by reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to

```
'query' => User::find()->where(['<>','is_super',1]),
```

Or,

```
<?php
$super = 1; 
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
  'query' => User::find()->where(['<>','is_super',$super]),
  'pagination' => [
      'pageSize' => 20,
  ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: Still returns an error of ...[Only variables should be passed by reference]

Comment: Try, `$super=1; 'query' => User::find()->where(['<>','is_super',$super]),` @GEOFFREYMWANGI

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
'query' => User::find()->where('is_super<>:is_super',[':is_super' => 1]),
```

Comment: Thanks works, but the first answer above worked ...thanks